# problems with java3D lib configuration

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, exception, java-3d

ive ran into some trouble configuring java3D to work with my IDE environment...

I have downloaded j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586.zip, and unpacked j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, vecmath.jar, libj3dcore-ogl.so, libj3dcore-ogl-cg.so and added them all as 'Referenced Libraries' within my project folder. this gets rid of any compilation warnings I was getting but when I compile and run the application I get the following exception!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline$1.run(NativePipeline.java:231)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibrary(NativePipeline.java:200)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibraries(NativePipeline.java:157)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:987)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:299)
    at Hello3d.<init>(Hello3d.java:10)
    at Hello3d.main(Hello3d.java:18)
```

here is a quick look at the source code as well. NOTE: Eclipse pulled in the import libraries paths automatically with Ctrl+Shift+O once they were added as Referenced Libraries.

```
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class Hello3d {

    public Hello3d(){
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
        group.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Hello3d();
    }
}
```

im not sure what im meant to do with 'j3dcore-ogl' but im stuck at this point. how do you install java3D within the system environment or the IDE project? please help.

IDE: Eclipse SDK 3.5.2

JVM: java-6-sun-1.6.0.22

OS: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 27):

I know this question is now a few years old, but the answers here were not enough for me to solve the problem. They only helped partially. http://www.filsa.net/2008/07/17/eclipse-java3d-and-javalibrarypath/ was also a bit helpful, but it was still not enough. Therefore I felt obliged to write a complete checklist to have Java3D work in Eclipse.

A few months ago, I already had the same problem and I somehow solved it without really understanding what I did. Today I wanted to set up my environment on a different computer and guess what, I had the same problem again. And I forgot what I had to do... This time however, I solved the problem more systematically and now I understand every step.

**The Solution - every step in detail**

**1)** If you are importing someone else's project, make sure to have the correct JDK and JRE installed and selected in Eclipse. My Eclipse had selected the latest JRE 7. The only one I had installed. But the Project that I work on requires JDK 6 and JRE 6. I recommend the following structure on your file system if you need to have multiple java versions

- *somePath/Java/JDK/JDK6/*
- *somePath/Java/JDK/JDK7/*
- *somePath/Java/JRE/JRE6/*
- *somePath/Java/JRE/JRE7/*
- *somePath/Java/Java3D/*

**2)** In **Eclipse**, you will have to do the following steps to **select the correct JDK and JRE**.

- *Project > Properties > Java Compiler*, check "Enable project specific settings", then select the correct **Compiler compliance level** for your project. In my case it's **1.6** for the use with **JDK6**. (The naming was really confusing for me, at least the 6 was a hint.)
- You also have to make sure that the correct **JRE** is used when you run the application. Therefore open *Run>Run Configurations* and select the tab JRE. If you use JDK 6, then you have to make sure that JRE 6 is used. You can add JREs if you click onto "Installed JREs" and then add the *somePath/Java/JRE/JRE6/* directory.

**3)** Having your Java environment set up correctly, make sure that **Java3D** is installed on your machine. You can't do anything wrong with this.

**4)** In your Java3D installation directory, locate the files

- **j3dcore-ogl.dll** (for Windows; on Linux it's j3dcore-ogl.so)
- **j3dcore.jar**
- **j3dutils.jar**
- **vecmath.jar**

It doesn't matter where these files are located if you setup your environment correctly, which I will explain. So if you want, you can copy these files into your project directory to have everything you need in one place.

**5)** Having located these files, make sure that

- On your Operating System, the location of **j3dcore-ogl.dll** is added to the **PATH** variable. The .dll or .so file contains machine native code that Java3D uses. Your system needs to be aware of this code's existence.
  Under Windows, to set the PATH variable, you open the System Settings in your Control Panel and select Advanced System Settings. On the bottom you will find the button "Environment Variables". In the System Variables list you will find the variable "Path". Make sure the directory of j3dcore-ogl is included in the list of paths.
- Back in Eclipse, wherever the *.jar files currently are, make sure they are included in your *Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries*. You can add them by either using **Add JARs** or **Add External JARs**, depending on whether you copied the three JARs to the project directory or not.

**6)** Now comes the part that saved my day today.

For each of the Java3D Libraries listed in the Java Build Path

- j3dcore.jar
- j3dutils.jar
- vecmath.jar,

you need to specify **Native Library Location**. The Native library is the **j3dcore-ogl.dll**, so edit the native library location to point to the directory containing j3dcore-ogl.dll.

I believe, that these are all steps that must be done to setup Java3D in eclipse, because I set up everything on a fresh computer today. Now I hope that these instructions will save some other poor Java-beginners', students' or programmers' day :-)

Comment: Obsolete and very complicated installation, rather follow these instructions: http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb

Answer (score 7):

Java is complaining because it cannot find the native libraries (the *.so files) on your system path that Java3D comes with.  Exactly how you fix this is up to you.  You can do anyone  one of the following:

1) Make sure that your system path includes the *.so files provided with Java3D

2) Setup your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable:
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/"path-to-java3d-libraries"/

3) Set the java.library.path when executing java:
   java -Djava.library.path=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/"path-to-java3d-libraries"/

To be sure you have things set correctly, add the following to your Java code and make sure the path reported contains the shared libraries on it

```
System.out.println("LD Library Path:" + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

Comment: Rather use Java 3D 1.6.0. Look at my answer. There is no need to deal with native libraries manually with the latest version of Java 3D.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a very old question but some developers are still installing an obsolete version of Java 3D which is harder to use with or without an IDE. Please rather use Java 3D 1.6.0 and follow my detailed instructions (in English and in French) available [here](http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb).

Comment: and fomr maven whe can we found the artifact?

Comment: The very latest version of Java3D isn't on Maven Central but we plan to put Java3D 1.7.0 into it this year.

Comment: @gouessej: did that ever happen?

Comment: @JonasVautherin Please ask this question to Phil on the official JogAmp forum in the Java3D section: http://forum.jogamp.org/java3d-f3728156.html As far as I know, it's not on Maven Central yet but if you ask for it, it will probably motivate Phil to upload it ;) Seriously, if it's useful for you, ask for it politely, it won't be a problem. Another user asked for it some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to given answers, what helped me set java 3d was:
Copy and paste all the .dll files from "C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.X\bin\" to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\". 
So form Java3D to my actual jre6(from bin to bin).

Previously I also set the classpath/(you can also set path) to 
3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, vecmath.jar, j3dcore-ogl.dll
but still did not work.

After copy past j3dcore-ogl.dll (described above) and left classpath to 3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, vecmath.jar  (in "C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.X\ext\") it worked fine.

I have found help here: http://www.xinapse.com/Manual/install_windows.html
Look at the point 2.

Best regards

Comment: It's a very bad idea. If you copy the native libraries into the JVM instead of setting the Java library path, you will break all applets and Java applications using a different version of Java 3D and/or JOGL. Moreover, you use an obsolete version. Rather use Java 3D 1.6.0. Look at my answer. There is no need to deal with native libraries manually with the latest version of Java 3D.

Comment: @ gouessej Thank you for your comment. 
Yes, my version is obsolete but still it worked and till now I have not got any problems with it.  Anyway, I will change it to 1.6.0 as you suggested and to avoid any problems in the future. 
Also as I have mentioned I left my classpath set.
I would like to say that you wrote very good material on the blog: [@ gouessej blog](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#introduction) 
B/R

Comment: It works but you don't benefit of our bugfixes. For example, Java 3D 1.5 simply crashes under Windows with some Intel (Q35 Express) and AMD (Radeon 3500) drivers. As I fixed those bugs in JOGL 2.2, only Java 3D 1.6.0 benefits of them. Thank you very much for your compliment. I have improved my article a lot thanks to the feedbacks of other JogAmp users.

Answer (score 0):

project/properties/java build path/source tab/expand and select native library location / navigate to i386 folder.

Comment: Rather use Java 3D 1.6.0. There is no need to deal with the native library location with the latest version of Java 3D as the native libraries are stored into some JARs, JOGL automatically detects the OS and the architecture, extracts them from JARs and loads them.

Answer (score 0):

(Windows same problem resolved)

```
"java.library.path" = PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\
(inside this folder: javaws.exe, javaw.exe,java.exe)
```

copy: `j3dcore-ogl.` "dll" to this folder and try!

Answer (score 0):

For netbeans (12.2 here), you have also to add the 3 external libraries dependency (j3dCore.jar, j3dutils.jar, vecmath.jar), but you cannot do the "native library location" addition as mentionned for Eclipse project, so instead you have to :

- go to your project properties,
- go in "run" catergory,
- add in "WM options" the following (adjust the path to yours):

`-Djava.library.path="C:\Local\Java\Java3D\1.5.1\bin"`

Also add in your system path the correct path to the  j3dcore-ogl.dll library, in my case again ' C:\Local\Java\Java3D\1.5.1\bin '  (adjust to yours)

Hope it helps Netbeans users.

Also, the j3d version i installed is old but i needed it to test old project.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to this code, it's help me:

```
  GraphicsConfiguration config =
       SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();

    Canvas3D canvas3D = new Canvas3D(config);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Solved it setting the Native path:

Properties - java build path - libraties - java3Dlib - Native library location - External folder -----> find the path: ....Java/Java3D/1.5.1/bin or the path where is the file: j3dcore-ogl.dll

Comment: Obsolete version. Rather use Java 3D 1.6.0. Look at my answer. There is no need to deal with native libraries manually with the latest version of Java 3D.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED - JonnyO answer is right.

I am using java 8 on linux, and downloaded from https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html (take the linux-amd64 version for an intel 64 bit system).

After unzipping the downloaded file, and then unzipping the contained j3d-jre.zip and adding the jar files to project and the libj3dcore-ogl.so to the jar, it still did not work. I had to add the libj3dcore-ogl.so to the library path. (Lazy as I am, I just copied it to /usr/lib, what is sufficient.)

Now it is working.

PS: Make sure to remove any other j3dcore.jar and j3dutils.jar beforehand.

Comment: JohnnyO's answer isn't correct, he uses an obsolete version of Java3D and the webpage you quote will be removed as Oracle stopped maintaining Java3D 1.5 at least 6 years ago. Moreover, putting native libraries into /usr/lib can break applications using Java Webstart and/or applets if they use another version of Java3D as your obsolete native library will be loaded in priority, defeating the purpose of setting the library path.

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact problem and the solution for me (I use eclipse) was to download the 32-bit (i586) (from https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html) archive and use those natives.

Comment: Obsolete version. Rather use Java 3D 1.6.0. Look at my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I recently ran into this same problem, here's how I fixed it:

Run 'strace java *filename*' and look near the top for lines like "*open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/libpthread.so*" which will tell you what binaries your system is loading.

In my case, it's amd64 that matters.

Go back to the java3d download page and download the binaries for (in this case) amd64 verson and install that. Overwrite the .so files in lib/ext (vecmath, j3dcore, and j3dutils).

Test your java3d program again, it should be working.

Comment: You mustn't copy the JARs into lib/ext because it may cause conflicts when several applets or applications require different incompatible versions of Java3D (and JOGL) and anyway the extension mechanism has been removed from Java 1.9 (i.e no lib/ext in Java 1.9). What you advise is a typical bad practice. Moreover, there is no need to deal with native libraries manually with the latest version of Java 3D, there is nothing to "install", just put the right JARs into the classpath of your application and it works. Copying JARs into the JRE impacts all programs using it, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score -3):

I had this problem.

it is enough you download java3d plugin and install it.

in your search engine like Google search "java3d plugin"

and download so install it.

Comment: Simply installing the plugin again won't necesarily add them to the library path, or tell the IDE where to find them.