# JAVA3D- First program- error

Tags: java-3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problems with java3D lib configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098161/problems-with-java3d-lib-configuration)

I want to make a 3d game using JAVA on **Ubuntu**, thus I downloaded `j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586.zip` from `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR`, extracted it. In **Eclipse**, I add the 3 jars in `../j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586/lib/ext/` in eclipse, then wrote this code

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;

public class Hello3d {
    public Hello3d() {
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
        group.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Hello3d();
    }

}
```

**got these errors**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Access restriction: The constructor SimpleUniverse() is not accessible due to restriction on required library /home/emil/Downloads/j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586/lib/ext/j3dutils.jar    Hello3d.java    /Checker3D/src  line 7  Java Problem

    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Access restriction: The constructor BranchGroup() is not accessible due to restriction on required library /home/emil/Downloads/j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586/lib/ext/j3dcore.jar    Hello3d.java    /Checker3D/src  line 8  Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Access restriction: The constructor ColorCube(double) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /home/emil/Downloads/j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586/lib/ext/j3dutils.jar   Hello3d.java    /Checker3D/src  line 9  Java Problem
```

**and more like those**
I set the "`Forbidden reference (access rules)`" under the "`Deprecated and restricted API`" from "`**Error**`" to "`**Warning**`".

**on building**
I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline$1.run(NativePipeline.java:231)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibrary(NativePipeline.java:200)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibraries(NativePipeline.java:157)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:987)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:299)
    at Hello3d.<init>(Hello3d.java:7)
    at Hello3d.main(Hello3d.java:15)
```

in **Run--->Run Configuration ---> JAVA applications--->(x=)arguments--->VM argiments**, I added

```
-Djava.library.path=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/emil/Downloads/j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586/lib/i386/
```

I got that error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Checker
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Checker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Checker. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer cheers!

Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries 1. New: J3DAll, 2. Add JARs.. select all three at ..\jre6\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, vecmath.jar

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Add Library .. -> User Library -> Next select J3DAll Finish
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export Top J3DAll